# Merge two dataframes based on chronological order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I have two dataframes with 2 columns, the first column is the column duration and takes float values e.g 239.4 hours and the second column is the column event and is either 0 or 1, 0 represents failure and 1 represent success. If the event value change then a new event is triggered. What I want is to track the changes in each dataframe and then merge them based on chronological order. Note that an event can have a duration of 0.007 h and duration of thousands of hours so the events are not evenly spaced. I cannot figure out how to do it.

An example of the dataframes and how the result should look like:

| Duration | Event |
| --- | --- |
| 0.06 | 0 |
| 2340 | 1 |
| 145 | 0 |

| Duration | Event |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | 1 |
| 1200 | 0 |
| 124 | 1 |

the result should look like this

| Duration | Event | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.06 | 0 | State 0 |
| 2340 | 1 | State 1 |
| 9 | 1 | State 2 |
| 1200 | 0 | State 3 |
| 124 | 1 | State 4 |
| 145 | 0 | State 5 |

Comment: You want a chronological order, but why is the Duration column in the result not ordered? Can you explain why for example 2340 is state 1 while 9 is state 2?

Comment: Because is the duration of simulations that run in parallel. State 0 is achieved n 0.06 hours, state 1 in 2340 hours, in the same time in the other simulation state 2 is finished before the event that last 2340 hours and the event with 1200 hours start (state 3) and so on.

Comment: I don't get the question. I'm sure what you are trying to do is simple. Can you add more data points? Unable to see any pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'duration': [0.06, 2340, 145], 'Event': [0, 1, 0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'duration': [9.0, 1200, 124], 'Event': [1, 0, 1]})
df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer').sort_values(by = ['duration'])
```

Output:

|  | duration | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.06 | 0 |
| 3 | 9.00 | 1 |
| 5 | 124.00 | 1 |
| 2 | 145.00 | 0 |
| 4 | 1200.00 | 0 |
| 1 | 2340.00 | 1 |

Comment: No, at time t=0 the events starts, the first event has a duration of 0.06sec, this is the state 0, when it finishes event 2 begins with duration 2340 hours this is state 1, in the other dataframe the event 0 is running and last 9 hours, therefore it will finish before the state 1 and the event with duration 1200 hours will start. The simulations run in parallel.